# Is there a single word for "stall attender"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I would like to put in my resume that I have voluntarily attended a particular stall to promote a social section in the university and introduce that to the new students.

But what is the title for such a duty?

I look for a professional word that add value to a resume.

Comment: Were it me, I think I would focus on the service you were promoting, perhaps including the word "promoter" in the title.  I don't in any case know of a word other than "stall tender" - but that includes things like serving tea and biscuits.

Comment: Attendant or host is common in British usage.

Comment: As a native speaker of AmE, when I read "stall attender," I think of the employee who hands out towels and wipes up spills in the restroom/WC/lavatory of a fancy hotel/restaurant/nightclub.

Comment: You attend an event and you are employed as an attendant (in some capacity). You can also **host a booth**. However, to attend a stall is pretty meaningless. attender is not a real word, only attendee, one who attends events. You're looking for: host a booth

Comment: You advised new students on social groups at the university.

Answer (score 0):

"Marketer" "Promoter" "Evangelist" "Outreach/Communications" (e.g., I was/did outreach/communications for the National Conservation Fund...) "Attendant" "Representative".

For resumes, you title is arbitrary and internal, but your "role" for that "position" should speak to your main responsibilities.  I.e., what you did, not where you stood.